# Captura de Vídeos, FFmpeg

Tags: vídeo

Tenho um programa escrito em Node.Js que utiliza o seguinte comando FFmpeg para capturar vídeos:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video=Integrated Webcam -c:v libx264 -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 60 -segment_format mp4 out%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4
```

Há a necessidade pelo projeto do vídeo ser interrompido a qualquer hora por meio de um botão. Quando finalizado pelo comando:

```
taskkill /im ffmpeg.exe /t /f
```

o vídeo é corrompido e não pode ser reproduzido.

Alguma maneira de finalizar o processo mas preservando o conteúdo gravado?

Comment: Acho que não, quando vc força e finaliza o ffmpeg ele deixa de escrever todos os cabeçalhos contendo as informações para a leitura do vídeo, geralmente o encode e o cabeçalho é escrito depois que todo o processo de captura é feito..

Comment: Eu já vi algumas "gambiarras" algumas pessoas usam um `stdin`e enviam um comando de `exit(q)` para finalizar o ffmpeg da maneira correta forçando ele escrever o vídeo da maneira adequada... olha aqui o que esse cara fez  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204174/how-do-i-close-a-node-js-ffmpeg-child-process-that-is-actively-streaming-from-a/14261781#14261781)

Comment: Resolvi o problema adicionando ao comando inicial o seguinte trecho: `-segment_format_options movflags=empty_moov`

Comment: Obrigada pelos comentários de vocês. Foram úteis para chegar a resposta final.